# why including the origin in a closed path causes discontinuity in complex functions like the square root?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am taking a complex analysis course and the professor confused me on the following matter:

On one hand, given a complex function like $f(z)=z^{1/2}$, when we complete a closed circuit around the origin there is a discontinuity problem - for example, if we start at $z=1$ with $\theta=0$ and end at $z=1$ with $\theta=2\pi$, the function $f(z)$ has a discontinuity along the positive x-axis.  on the other hand. if we do not include the origin, the problem is gone and the function remains continuous and single-valued.

I understand that the problem stems from the fact that if we include the origin, while we return to the same point we started with, the argument can complete a full cycle, which causes a phase difference that in turn affects the value of the function when we approach the point $z=1$ from the first or fourth quadrants. But why does including the origin cause the problem, contrary to when we traverse a closed path that does not include the origin?
why does including the origin cause this discontinuity, and why does leaving the origin out solve it?

Someone asked my professor this question, but he kept repeating that the reason for the discontinuity was that we included the origin in the circuit, and gave no more explanations...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not including the origin in the path that is the problem. It is *going all the way around* the origin with the path that is the problem. The thing is. if you look at the behavior of $z^2$ on the unit circle $|z| = 1$, if $z$ follows the circle from $1$ to $-1$, you see that $z^2$ goes all the way around the circle and is clear back to $1$ again. If $z$ itself finishes the circle, going from $-1$ to $1$, $z^2$ races around the circle a second time. So what happens when you take the inverse operation? Then $\sqrt z$ takes the place of $z$, while $z$ takes the place of $z^2$ in this.

Comment: When $z$ has made it all the way around the circle, $\sqrt z$ has only made it half-way. $z$ has looped from $1$ all the way back again, but $\sqrt z$ has only gone from $1$ to $-1$. But that is a problem for the function $f(z) = \sqrt z$. $f(z)$ can have only one value, and $f(1) = 1$. So as $z$ proceeds around the circle from $1$ to $i$, $\sqrt z$ goes from $1$ to $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}$. As $z$ goes to $-1, \sqrt z$ is at $i$, As $z$ goes to $-i$, $\sqrt z$ reaches $\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt 2}$. and as $z$ *approaches* $1$ again, $\sqrt z$ approaches $-1$. But we already have $\sqrt 1 = 1$

Comment: As $z$ approaches $1$ from below, $\sqrt z$ approaches $-1$, but as $z$ approaches $1$ from above, $\sqrt z$ approaches $1$. The square root has to make a jump of $2$ in its value. Now I assumed that jump was at $1$ here. But we could have made it somewhere else (most commonly it is taken at -1 instead). That choice is the branch cut.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for your answer. I understand the points you raised, the thing that is still not clear is the reason why making a circuit all the way around the origin causes this problem. I thought about it and think that the reason is that when we make a full relovution around the origin the argument changes $2\pi$, while we return to the same point.

Comment: Then, since we assume we choose $w(z)=e^{i\theta/2}$, as you said there is a difference of 2 units when aproaching from below or above, because substituting 0 for theta, we get 1, and when we substitute $2\pi$ we get -1. This happens because the argument/angle is defined relative to the origen, and when we complete a circuit around the origin, theta must change $2\pi$. When we do not include the origin, theta can return to its original value when we return to the same point, so the problem is gone.

Comment: As you move $z$ a full rotation around the origin, your value of $\sqrt z$ only moves a half rotation around the origin, so it ends up opposite where it started.

Comment: The reason going around the origin is a problem is because when $z$ goes around the origin, $\sqrt z$ only goes halfway around the origin. The reason the origin is a problem as opposed to other points is because $\sqrt z$ is not differentiable at the origin. Circling non-removable singularities of otherwise analytic functions generally have this problem that circling them picks up some non-zero value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate Karl's and Paul Sinclair's comments geometrically:

[image: Two representations of the Riemann surface of square root]

(There's more explanation in this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766481/clarification-on-riemann-surfaces-and-branch-cuts).)